# IIS: HTTPS site with sub application

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl, https

I'm currently in the process of installing an application for a site that's built with https enabled.

In the test site where only http is used I'm able to test the sub

folder application and have it work correctly as a separate application in IIS.

```
http://www.mysite.com - redirects to https
http://www.mysite.com/myApp
```

When I then port this over to the live environment the applications pages show as being completely blank returning a HTTP 500 error in Chrome developer tools.

```
https://www.mysite.com site works 
http://www.mysite.com/myApp - 500 - internal server error
https://www.mysite.com/myApp - 500 - internal server error
```

In both instanances with the subfolder application 'myApp' I've made sure that internal links for the web pages I have within my app include the correct protocol.

Does anyone know if any means by which I can essentially inherit, or copy the settings for SSL certification from the main site to get the application working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the detailed error message say?  I don't think it is related to the SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myApp should be a Virtual Directory, in IIS Manager right click on your main site, and Add Virtual Directory, name the Alias myApp or what have you, and browse to the path folder.